# Issue Creating Two MX Records with Different Priority Using Google Domains

Tags: mx-record

How do I add another MX record to Google Domains that uses a lower priority? When I try to add the lower priority MX record it gives me this error, "Record already in use". [image]

I followed Google's instruction here, [image]

Comment: I am experiencing exactly this problem May 6, 2020.  It looks like I can only have ONE MX Record.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should click the Edit button in the MX record that Google considers valid, click '+' and add the second MX record

Comment: It works when I click the "+" next to the existing MX record.  Do Not click the "Add" button!